# Search box to find multiple markers with same property in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a json file with a property product ID. I need to find the markers having the same product ID and display it on the map. I used the custom search plugin present in the leaflet. But it searches only one marker at a time and displays on the map. But in my case I have multiple markers with same product ID. Could anyone help me on this? Are there any otehr plugins avalilable to search multiple markers and display on the map?

Comment: Chek this answer here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175863/adding-one-search-box-for-multiple-geojson-polygon-layers/175869#175869 search extension need to be targeting multiple Json feature  .in default it targets only one.